# Why is maven dependency plugin failing?

Tags: maven

I have a project (call it project-C) I'm trying to analyze with the maven dependency plugin. The project executes the `package` goal with no problems but when I issue `mvn dependency:tree` I get

`Failed to execute goal on project project-B: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:project-B:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.mycompany:project-A:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT from/to com.cloudera (https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/): Failed to transfer file: https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com/mycompany/project-A/0.5.0-SNAPSHOT/project-A-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict.`

Now both project A and project B are in the local repository and they're dependencies of project C so I don't see why maven is trying to transfer them from (or to?) cloudera. Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: can you try building the other two dependency projects A and B first and then building the actual project C

Comment: @Sravya Project A builds fine with `mvn compile`. Project B (depends on A) doesn't. I get: `Failed to execute goal on project Project B: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:Project B:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.mycompany:Project A:jar:0.5.0-SNAPSHOT from/to com.cloudera (https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/): Failed to transfer file: https://repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com/mycompany/Project A/0.5.0-SNAPSHOT/Project A-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Return code is: 409 , ReasonPhrase:Conflict. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: I guess you should do  mvn install not just compile